# is there a way to add a fk to appUser in abpframework

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, abp

```
public class AppUser : FullAuditedAggregateRoot<Guid>, IUser
    {
        // Base properties
        public virtual Guid? CabinetId { get; private set; }
    }
```

i added cabinetId as a property but I want to implement one-to-one relationship between (appuser and appuser) with CabinetId as the Fk and I cant find a way to do that ,
i tried using dataAnnotations and tried to configurate the relationship in the fluent api but nothing works

Comment: Do you want to create relationship between AppUser and Cabinet?

Comment: You can take a look at this https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/7105#issuecomment-757641838

Comment: @maliming thank you this is what i was looking for